# How does one make a double widehat?

Tags: symbols

To depict the Fourier transform of the Fourier transform of a function f, I want to make two widehats over each other as in `\widehat{\widehat{f}}`, however, this makes the widehats not immediately over each other. How would one make the widehats immediately above each other?

Comment: For instance `$\skew{5.5}\widehat{\widehat{f}}$` or `$\skew{1.2}\widehat{\widehat{g}}$`. I'm afraid that one has to fine tune them by hand.

Comment: BTW, TL2012 versions of LuaTeX and XeTeX will support proper positioning for stacked accents like this (for OpenType math fonts only in case of XeTeX).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you need the wide version? AMS provides  `\Hat` accent that shifts when doubled, but the package doesn't provide a wide version that does this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\Hat{\Hat{f}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually amsmath contains code to make stacked widehat work but it is commented out for some reason. If you copy the code and uncomment widehat  you get:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\makeatletter
\def\@tempa#1{\@xp\@tempb\meaning#1\@nil#1}
\def\@tempb#1>#2#3 #4\@nil#5{%
  \@xp\ifx\csname#3\endcsname\mathaccent
    \@tempc#4?"7777\@nil#5%
  \else
    \PackageWarningNoLine{amsmath}{%
      Unable to redefine math accent \string#5}%
  \fi
}
\def\@tempc#1"#2#3#4#5#6\@nil#7{%
  \chardef\@tempd="#3\relax\set@mathaccent\@tempd{#7}{#2}{#4#5}}


\@tempa\widehat
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
\widehat{\widehat{f}}
\widehat{\widehat{abcd}}
\]
\end{document}
```

The `amsmath` documentation actually mentions why `\widehat` is omitted, but I think if you don't needed the wider wide hats provided by the `amsfonts` definition, using the `amsmath` stacking version is OK.

```
For widehat and
widetilde, we need to avoid clobbering the definitions done by the
\pkg{amsfonts} package. Arbitrating the contention between
\pkg{amsmath} and \pkg{amsfonts} to allow doubling a widetilde
accent looks tricky, so for the time being [mjd,1999/07/19] we just
leave \cn{widehat} and \cn{widetilde} alone.
```

Comment: Also `\hat{\hat{f}}` works. The capitalized version remains for compatibility, but double accents are treated well with the normal commands.

Comment: @egreg, so it does, the code also seems to work reasonably with widehat as well, see updated answer

Comment: Out of votes, ATM. :) Maybe @barbarabeeton can take note.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! For completion, I should remark that if I have `\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}` in the preamble instead, the above trick reverts to the standard behavior of `\widehat{\widehat{f}}` that occurs when you do nothing. To get around this, it seems that at least for double widehat-ing single letters one does `\widehat{\widehat{f\, }}` with the code in the answer above. However, for multiple letters like `abcd`, using amssymb doesn't affect the output of `\widehat{\widehat{abcd}}`

Comment: Well no actually, maybe you should give that as an answer. If you use `f\,` then you don't need the redefinition at all as if the argument to (any) accent command isn't a single character it breaks the automatic shifting due to italic correction, so both accents are simply centered so they line up naturally.

Comment: No actually I do still need the redefinition. Suppose I have two files. One uses amssymb and one does not. To get the output in the second picture above when I also have amssymb, I have to use `f\,` but I can still use `\widehat{\widehat{abcd}}`.

Answer (score 3):

The [MathTime Professional 2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) package (`mtpro2` for short) provides methods for producing really really wide-hat symbols (as well as wide-tilde and wide-check symbols) and stacking these symbols, i.e., producing doubled widehat symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$\widehatdown{1.5pt}{\widehat{aceuvw}}$

\bigskip
$\widehatdown{2.5pt}{\widehat{A+B+C+D+E+F+G }}$
\end{document}
```

I must confess I hope you have no need for the lower of the two examples... Note also that the `mtpro2` package produces Times Roman-type math fonts, which may or may not be a look you like.

Answer (score -1):

`$\widehat{\widehat{f\,}}\!\!$` seems to work somehow.

(Based on comments by David Carlisle and ADF.)