# Double widetilde

Tags: symbols, accents

Is there a standard/good way to obtain a "double widetilde" in LaTeX?

Using `$\widetilde{\widetilde{A}}$` the tildes are too separate to my taste. I'd like them to look like a single (double) accent, not like an accent on top of another.

In other words, is there a way to control the distance between widetildes when nested? or otherwise, a natural way to appropriately define such an accent?

Thank you!

Comment: The answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54712/how-does-one-make-a-double-widehat should be relevant.

Comment: The `\widetilde` command provided by the package `kpfonts` (which is a font package, so if you use it you get a different font) also (like MathTimes Pro) stack nicely; though there is no option to fine-tune.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code reduces by 10% the height of the box formed with a single wide tilde and adds another one on top of it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doublewidetilde}[1]{{%
  \mathpalette\double@widetilde{#1}%
}}
\newcommand{\double@widetilde}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\widetilde{#2}$}%
  \ht\z@=.9\ht\z@
  \widetilde{\box\z@}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\doublewidetilde{abc}_{\doublewidetilde{abc}_{\doublewidetilde{abc}}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]